# different cloudfront responses depending on request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm getting strange results when making requests through a .NET core application hosted in AWS.
When I use one ID in the request:

```
https://example.org/bar/123
```

I get back a 200 and I see this in the headers:

```
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
```

But if I change the ID from 123 to e.g. 456:

```
https://example.org/bar/456
```

I get back a 502 error (not coming from our code) and I see this in the headers:

```
 x-cache: Error from cloudfront
```

I don't have any logging in place, so I can't tell why this is happening. Why the difference in x-cache values?

Answer (score 0):

Your server returned a 502 error the first time you requested `https://example.org/bar/456`. When you requested that URL again, rather than do the same request, CloudFront cached the error, and just returned the error again (hence the `x-cache: Error from cloudfront`, or in other words, we're returning a cached error rather than asking your server again).

You can change the default error caching behaviour in CloudFront if we wish to.